# Create a computer Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-exchange

Have you guys thought about creating a computer Stack Exchange site? One where users could post computer problems and get answers from the community. Maybe this already exists, but I just don't know about it. Please, post your thoughts.

This idea has been proposed on Area 51: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/26032/computer-world

Comment: Finally, a place to ask about where to buy some RAM and the best router on the market. Not to mention, which ISP is better.

Comment: @random : thats exactly what i'm talking about.

Comment: This probably belongs on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Greg : I don't know much about Area 51.

Comment: Area 51 is where we propose new Stack Exchange sites. It's a cool process.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Do you mean like [Super User](https://superuser.com/)?

From the FAQ:

> ### What kind of questions can I ask here?
>
> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …
>
> - computer hardware
> - computer software
>
> and it is not about …
>
> - videogames or consoles
> - websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress
> - electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer
> - a shopping or buying recommendation

Comment: It looked to me like the OP wanted a place that allowed shopping recommendations.  Look at randoms comment and Linuxmints response.